# a little trivial query about for loops and variable assigning

Tags: java

I am 'warming up' with some of the exercises on codingbat, and I am playing with the "tenrun" one which says

For each multiple of 10 in the given array, change all the values following it to be that multiple of 10, until encountering another multiple of 10. So {2, 10, 3, 4, 20, 5} yields {2, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20}.

i guess there are hundreds of ways to do that, i wanted to try out the simple idea of setting a counter variable to equals the element multiple by ten and assign it to the next variables until it meets the next one :

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
     if (nums[i] % 10 == 0) { count = nums[i]; }
     else  { nums[i] = count; }
 }
```

in the main method i am putting `int  [] yuk={20,10,0,0,6,0,56};` and i expect to get `yuk={20,10,10,10,10,10,10}` .Instead it gives  `yuk={20,10,0,0,6,0,56};`
it does not assign the count correctly and returns the same input array.
part of a more general question, how does the variable passing within the for/loops statement works ?

Comment: Where is `count0` defined?

Comment: sorry its a count in the code, it was a type from my side

Comment: Your code does what it should, except it initializes all the elements before the first multiple of 10 to 0. Please provide a full, runnable example, and tell us what it does instead of what you expect it to do. And indent it properly.

Comment: Seems like setting `count = nums[0]` before the loop, but after checking to make sure `nums.length` is greater than 0 would fix everything.

Comment: Your code doesn't use any `yuk` variable. It uses a `nums` variable. And the result, if `nums` is initialized to `{20,10,0,0,6,0,56}`, is `[20, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, as expected, since 0 is a multiple of 10. Will you finally provide a complete runnable example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more condition to your if statement to check for equality to zero:

```
if (nums[i] % 10 == 0&&nums[i]!=0) {
            count = nums[i];
        } else {
            nums[i] = count;
        }
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: i put int  [] yuk={20,10,0,0,6,0,56}; and i got yuk={20,10,0,0,6,0,56};, i expected yuk={20,10,10,10,10,10,10}

Comment: works like charm, i just need to figure out why wasn't the first code executing :)

Comment: It wasn't working because 0 is considered a multiple of 10 so the code will set the array elements to 0 once it encounters one.

Comment: Doesn't work if the input starts with something that is not a multiple of 10. With this input: {12,13,20,10,0,0,6,0,56}, it produces this: {0,0,20,10,10,10,10,10,10}.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean shouldChange = false;
int changeToValue = 0;
for (int i = 0;  i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] % 10 == 0 && nums[i] != 0) {
       shouldChange = true;
       changeToValue = nums[i];
    } else if (shouldChange) {
       nums[i] = changeToValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: tested it , but it assignes 0's to the rest of the values, not the array's ellement

Comment: Since `0 % 10 == 0` is true, it provides the correct output. If you don't want to include 0 as a multiple of 10, then an extra check is needed, as provided in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public int[] tenRun(int[] nums) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        if (nums[i] % 10 == 0) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length && !(nums[j] % 10 == 0); j++) {
                nums[j] = nums[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return nums;

}
```

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow . help me with your suggestion to improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple one

```
public int[] tenRun(int[] nums) {
  boolean detected = false;
  int value = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){

    if( detected ){// after detecting multiple of 10
      if(nums[i]%10 == 0) value = nums[i]; // detected another multiple of 10 ,changing value
      nums[i] = value; // assign detected multiple of 10
    }

    if(nums[i]%10 == 0){ // detect first multiple of 10
        detected = true;
        value = nums[i]; //assign it to value
    }
  }
 return nums; 
}
```